# How to import GIF in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to prepare my portfolio website with Nextjs. I want to use gif in the site. You can find my code below. I could not find how to do it.

[image]

Comment: and also i can download the gif file to the computer

Comment: Don't post code in images, post them in text. Additionally, "I could not find how to do it" - What does that mean? Please be specific when asking questions, and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions.

Comment: @AndyRay 
I stated my main question in the title. I also tried to throw the code as text, but because it didn't look the way I wanted in the preview, I took a screenshot. Next time I'll be more careful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next/Image does support GIF files...my first thought would be to ask if you have explicitly whitelisted a set of external domains in your `next.config.js` file? For the Next/Image Loader to handle external domains they must be individually whitelisted. Here are the contents of my next.config.js file.

```js
const path = require('path');
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: !!process.env.ANALYZE
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
    webpack(
        config,
        {
            dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
        }
    ) {
        if (isServer) {
            require('./scripts/generate-sitemap');
        }
        /**
         * !dev ? preact/compat : react, react-dom on build
         * reduce page weight in production by ~10%
         */
        if (!dev && !isServer) {
            Object.assign(
                (config.resolve.alias['@/'] = path.resolve('./')),
                {
                    react: 'preact/compat',
                    'react-dom': 'preact/compat'
                }
            );
        }
        return config;
    },
    sourceMaps: {
        productionBrowserSourceMaps: true
    },
    images: {
        domains: [
            'avatars.githubusercontent.com',
            'faderoom-headless.us',
            'www.faderoom-headless.us',
            'dtmqnbkq3btfh.cloudfront.net',
            'secure.gravatar.com',
            'automattic.com',
            'serve.onegraph.com',
            'onegraph.com',
            'maps.google.com',
            'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
            'maps.gstatic.com',
            'thefaderoom146.booksy.com',
            'dev-3cqt2bq0.auth0.com',
            'scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net',
            'd2zdpiztbgorvt.cloudfront.net',
            'platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com',
            'square-postoffice-production.s3.amazonaws.com'
        ]
    },
    future: {
        webpack5: true,
        strictPostcssConfiguration: true
    },
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en-US'],
        defaultLocale: 'en-US'
    }
});

console.log(
    'next.config.js',
    JSON.stringify(module.exports, null, 2)
);
```

So you would have to whitelist `media.giphy.com` and it should work just fine. I also do recommend setting the quality prop for the `Image` component. Quality defaults to 75 out of 100 but I'd suggest making that closer to 100 for better UX.

Answer (score 4):

Next/Image now supports gifs.

You should be able to import the gif and then toss it into the src like this

```js
import Image from 'next/image';
import myGif from 'url'

...

<Image src={myGif} alt="my gif" height={500} width={500} />
```

If the url doesn't work here, it should work if you download the gif and toss it into assets.

Answer (score 0):

At first I entered your code:
[Your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgZFu.png)
and nextjs gave me this as an error:

[Screenshot erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE2K2.png)

So I added the domain 'media.giphy.com' in the configuration 'next.config.js'
This file must be added to the root of the project, at the same level as the 'pages' or 'lib' folder for example and must be called 'next.config.js':

[File place screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmyT.png)

And in it you have to put this:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['media.giphy.com']
    }
};
```

Then you have to restart your next js server.
And normally you get this:

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srufJ.png)

Here is some documentation to read to better understand:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the prop `unoptimized` to serve the image as it is:

make sure you white list your domain in the `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
 images: {
     domains: ['SOURCE_IMAGE_DOMAIN']
 }
};
```

then in your image component:

```
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image unoptimized={true} src={GIF} alt="the gif" height={500} width={500} />
```

Next documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#animated-images